# Hibernate criteria filter inner collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the next classes/tables:

### User

- id
- name
- works // list of work

### Work

- id
- name
- user_id

And the following code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("User"); 
criteria.list();
```

returns a list of `User`s that contain list of `Work` object assotiated with them (by id=user_id).

How can I modify this query to get the same list of `User` but with the follow restriction:
List of `Work` should not includes `Work`s where name ='fck'?

Comment: He want's to know how to get all the Works for a specific user (as far as my russian skills go). You either access them by calling getWorks() on the user instance, or you do a join (or possibly a join fetch if they're lazy loaded) on the two entities User and Work.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but not wise, because the loaded users wouldn't reflect the actual state of the database : their list of works should contain all their works, and not only some of them. Modifying them could lead to unwanted deletes in the database.

I would rather load the works you're interested in, with their associated user :

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Work.class, "work");
c.createAlias("work.user", "user");
c.setFetchMode("work.user", FetchMode.JOIN);
c.add(Restrictions.ne("work.name", "fck"));
```